# Seedstack with Spring batch integration

Tags: spring-batch, seedstack

how to run the job from the command line in seedstack using the capsule.jar? Is there any way we can add all the dependency in the jar so that we can avoid setting up the classpath? Is there any sample available?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the SeedStack [Capsule](http://www.capsule.io/) integration is to build an executable über-JAR containing all the dependencies needed to run the application. In that case you don't need to configure the classpath.

To build the capsule you must use the `package` goal of the SeedStack plugin, using this plugin section in the `pom.xml` of your module:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.seedstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>seedstack-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>build-capsule</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>package</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This will build the capsule JAR in the module `target` directory. This capsule JAR can be then run as a standard executable JAR:

```
java [jvm-args] -jar capsule.jar [app-args]
```

In your case you would run the batch job using:

```
java -jar capsule.jar run-job --job someJob
```

Relevant docs are available here:

- [Package goal](http://seedstack.org/docs/maven-plugin/package/)
- [SeedStack Spring Batch integration](http://seedstack.org/addons/spring-bridge/batch/)
- [Running SeedStack applications](http://seedstack.org/docs/core/)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way we can add all the dependency in the jar so that we can avoid setting up the classpath?

You can create an uber jar using:

- Spring Boot maven plugin: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html
- Maven shade plugin: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

> Is there any sample available?

You can find an example in the Spring Batch getting started sample: https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/ (see "Build an executable JAR" section)

Answer (score 0):

I have created sample sedstack cli project with pacakge as capsule and executed the same with below command :

java -jar my-cli-project-capsule.jar sample

It's works perfectly.

I have share the capsule at below location :
https://github.com/smohane/sudeshrepo/tree/seed-samples